# Code Crashes Visual Studio - Any way to rewrite this?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So, in vb.net when using this Expressions visual studio just hangs and crashes when trying to copy and paste it into a file, or when renaming the dto it's using. It's getting super frustrating so i'm wondering if anyone can help me rewrite it into something that doesn't crash vb, it looks like it doesn't crash in C# from the couple of tests i've done.

Code that crashes visual studio:

```vb
Public GetFooDetailsDto As Expression(Of Func(Of tblFoo, FooDetailsDto)) = Function(x) New FooDetailsDto With {
            .ID = x.FooID,
            .Name = x.FooName,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have error in related code because this does not crash Visual Studio. Note that I removed the `,` after `x.FooName`.

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Public Class FooDetailsDto
    Public ID As Integer
    Public Name As String
End Class

Public Class tblFoo
    Public FooID As Integer
    Public FooName As String
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
    End Sub

    Public GetFooDetailsDto As Expression(Of Func(Of tblFoo, FooDetailsDto)) = Function(x) New FooDetailsDto With {
            .ID = x.FooID,
            .name = x.FooName
        }

End Module
```

Comment: @Fred - Did that help?